# OracleCommand execution blocks if has OracleDependency

Tags: oracle10g, dependencies, notifications, oraclecommand

I have the following code:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString);
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select * from testtable", conn);
conn.Open();
OracleDependency.Port = 2010;
OracleDependency dependency = new OracleDependency(command);
command.AddRowid = true;
command.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;

dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

command.CommandTimeout = 1000;
DataTable t = new DataTable();
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
adapter.Fill(t);
conn.Close();
```

This is a very straightforward code that uses Oracle Notification Service to receive notifications about particular table changes.

My problem is that when I call `adapter.Fill(t);` the execution simply blocks. The command executes in an instance if there is no dependency attached to it so it's not the database or the data. I can see the call back registering with the database by querying the table `user_change_notification_regs` and have also opened the port specified (2010):

```
net8://(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST='myIp')(PORT=2010)))?PR=0
```

I am at wits end and rand out of things to try.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen an exception raised in a similar situation when I've tried to set the port number to a port already used on my machine.  As soon as I commented out setting the port number it ran fine, so perhaps you could try that?  And check "netstat -na" for used ports.

The exception I saw was:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-24912: Listener thread failed. Listen failed.
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
```

The confusing thing (at least for me) was the exception is raised not when the port is set, but later when the first query was executed against it.